Passing authorization token from one API to another failing
I need to pass an authentication token from one api to next. I have tried json extractor as follows. But the next api is still giving 401 unauthorized. Tried second api with direct token and it works
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

You have token variable declared in the JSON Extractor hence you need to change the ${bearertoken} in the HTTP Header Manager to just ${token}.
I cannot say that your JSONPath expression is correct without seeing the response, it worth checking the ${token} variable value using Debug Sampler

I have edited the pictures. can you please suggest now. one image was by mistake. It was ${token} only

You need to change your JSONPath expression to data.token. See Jayway JsonPath documentation and How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing article for more information on performing correlation of JSON data
